# MySQL integer as Date in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have a database where the months and years are saved in different columns as integers. The query is working fine but if the user of the application is selecting a timespan over several years the query isn't working how it should be.

```
WORKS FINE: 01-2014 <--> 04-2014
DOESN'T WORK: 12-2013 <--> 02-2014
```

Here is the original working query of the app:

```
SELECT tbl_report.YEAR, tbl_report.MONTH, tbl_question.ID, tbl_question.QUESTION , tbl_answer.ANSWER, tbl_question.TYPEID
FROM ....
WHERE tbl_report.CITYID = 'london' 
  AND  tbl_report.YEAR >= 2013 AND tbl_report.YEAR <= 2013 
  AND tbl_report.MONTH >= 8 AND tbl_report.MONTH <= 9
```

***How can I solve build a query in order to give right results back to the user***?

Comment: Are your columns named "month" and "year"?

Comment: @JohnConde Yes these are columns

Comment: that's because the STARTING month (12) is greater than the ENDING month (2).  Your logic won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need separate conditions for months that are in the same year as the start and stop year, and the other months.

For example, if you want records from 2013-10 and forward, you want the months 10, 11 and 12 from 2013, but all the months in the following years.

Example to get the records from 2012-05 to 2014-02:

```
where
  tbl_report.CITYID = 'london' and
  ((tbl_report.YEAR = 2012 and tbl_report.MONTH >= 5) or tbl_report.YEAR > 2012) and
  (tbl_report.YEAR < 2014 or (tbl_report.YEAR = 2014 and tbl_report.MONTH <= 2))
```

Comment: your solution is working perfect for my problem. thanks

Comment: `tbl_report.CITYID = 'london' and (tbl_report.YEAR = 2012 and tbl_report.MONTH >= 5 or tbl_report.YEAR = 2013 or tbl_report.YEAR = 2014 and tbl_report.MONTH <= 2)` Doesn't this more simple?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Yes, but that only works for a range that spans over exactly two years. The expression in the answer is usable for any year and month values that you put in it (as long as the end date is not after the start date of course).

Comment: In that case you can change `tbl_report.YEAR = 2013` by interval like `tbl_report.YEAR BETWEEN 2013 AND 2015`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Yes, but then you have one query for months in the same year, one query for months in consecutive years, one query for dates that span two years, and one query for dates that span three years and more. You can't just put the dates in the query, you need to analyse the dates to choose the right query.

Comment: So how this relates to OP?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: What do you mean?

Comment: Can you provide a continuous interval which this simple pattern not able to cover?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Either of two example intervals in the OP.

Comment: "WORKS FINE: 01-2014 <--> 04-2014" -> `tbl_report.YEAR = 2014 AND tbl_report.MONTH <= 4`, "DOESN'T WORK: 12-2013 <--> 02-2014" -> `tbl_report.YEAR = 2013 AND tbl_report.MONTH >= 12 OR tbl_report.YEAR = 2014 AND tbl_report.MONTH <= 2`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Yes, that shows what I mean. With that approach you need different queries for different dates. That means that you need to manually create a new query each time, or use complex code to dynamically create new queries.

Answer (score 2):

How much sense does this make to you? Give me a number less than or equal to 2 and greater than or equal to 12.

```
tbl_report.MONTH >= 12 AND tbl_report.MONTH <= 2
```

That will never be true!

As for a solution:

Try this in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE tbl_report.CITYID = 'london' AND
     (
        ((tbl_report.YEAR = 2013 AND tbl_report.MONTH >= 12) 
           OR tbl_report.YEAR > 2013)
        AND 
        ((tbl_report.YEAR = 2014 AND  tbl_report.MONTH <= 2) 
           OR tbl_report.YEAR < 2014)
     )
```

*** Updated to support multiple year spans. Not specified in the original question, but it is the more robust query.**

Comment: :) I know! I haven't worked with MySQL functions and I think this is the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you tell me the month, which belongs to this criteria?

Comment: @Derek It works! BUT JUST FOR A SPAN OF 1 YEAR. It doesn't work for 2012 till 2014! Just a twist in the relational operator (=>). thanks!

Comment: I never factored that into my original solution. Zeroed in on the particular problem too much. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

Just to solve this you can do something like this:

For the case of

```
 DOESN'T WORK: 12-2013 <--> 02-2014
```

Query will be

```
SELECT tbl_report.YEAR, tbl_report.MONTH, tbl_question.ID, tbl_question.QUESTION ,             tbl_answer.ANSWER, tbl_question.TYPEID
FROM ....
WHERE tbl_report.CITYID = 'london' 
  AND 
     ( tbl_report.YEAR > 2013 AND tbl_report.YEAR < 2014 
    OR tbl_report.MONTH >= 8 AND tbl_report.YEAR = 2013
    OR tbl_report.MONTH <= 9 AND tbl_report.YEAR = 2014)
```

But this sure looks like a bad design to me, when sql and most of the databases provide you datetime dataset and you can query something like:

```
where tabl_report.date between start_date and end_date;
```

Comment: `tbl_report.YEAR > 2013 AND tbl_report.YEAR < 2014` doesn't make sense, because no integer can match such a condition.

Comment: I was just writing a general query, in this case may be this doesn't make sense, but if the range is `12-2011` to `04-2016`, it will start to make sense.

Comment: Yes, I can see it now, thanks for the explanation. Perhaps it was the values you used as arguments in your example that confused me. I should have thought of them as variables, maybe then it would have made sense for me straight away. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tbl_report.YEAR = 2013 AND tbl_report.MONTH = 12
OR tbl_report.YEAR = 2014 AND tbl_report.MONTH BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Comment: I had to many results of the month 1 and 2. some cartesian product issue. But thx for ur time.

Comment: @codeshifter, What you mean? How you can get cartesian product? The predicate exactly what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing it this way:

```
...
AND (tbl_report.YEAR, tbl_report.MONTH) >= (2013, 12)
AND (tbl_report.YEAR, tbl_report.MONTH) <= (2014, 2)
```

This syntax is [valid in MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3688d/2) although it may not result in a very efficient query plan. But if it does work out well for you in your environment, you will end up with the cleanest and most intuitive query for your particular problem.